# What is meant by the norm of this object?

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, numerical-methods

I want to know how to interprete this norm 
$|\nabla\nabla f|$, where f is a vector?
Is it the Hessian? I think its a tensor? But how does it look like? I mean the components....

Comment: Giving the context would be helpful, as I don't think this is standard notation.

Comment: One step back: i mean $|D^2 f|$. With this i want to compute a discrete version $\nabla \nabla_h f$.

Comment: I'm sorry but that won't do. You'll have to work on your question a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

$D^2 f$ can be thought of as a symmetric bilinear form.  These can be represented as a matrix action $(D^2 f)_x (u, v) = u^T B_x v$ where $B_x$ is symmetric.  Associated with any matrix is an operator norm which for symmetric matrices is given by the maximum absolute value of its eigenvalues

Comment: Thank you, but if a is vector-valued, what are the components of this matrix? If $D f = \left( \begin{array}{c} \partial_1 f_1 \qquad \partial_2 f_1\\ \partial_1 f_2 \qquad \partial_2 f_2\\ \partial_1 f_3 \qquad \partial_2 f_3 \end{array} \right)$, what is $D^2 f$ ?